# Why does rubbing a coin on steel make vending machines accept it?

Tags: everyday-life

I have seen people scratching their coin against the vending machine in order to make it likelier to accept it.

[image: Illustration: notice the scrapped metal on this vending machine.]

Conceivably, this habit might be due to some confirmation bias and lacking any rational basis.

Provided that this practice is genuine, what would be the reason?

Comment: A guess? Static charge carried by the coin holder:  if the slit is not metalic, charge on the coin might give funny signals to the weighing machine. ?

Comment: You asked, "Provided that this practice is genuine..." Did you mean to ask, "Assuming that this practice actually works?" That's a big assumption. I think you need to establish that it _does_ actually work before anybody will want to join you in a substantial discussion about _why_ it works.

Comment: Note that some vending machines have the dedicated steel plate with the official sign like "Scratch coins here if they are not accepted".

Comment: This question might be more suited and appealing for the folks of Skeptics.SE :) They might even know if it is effective or not , with actual papers in support ! :)